# weird failure with "PhpThumbFactory"

Tags: php, image, zend-framework, thumbnails

I'm using the [PhpThumbFactory](http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/)-library inside of my Zend-Framework application. And it seems to execute (!?) the generated image file as PHP.

Error:

> [07-Mar-2011 11:20:20] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '' (ASCII=16) state=0 in path\uploads\thumbs\3.jpg on line 52
>
> [07-Mar-2011 11:20:20] PHP Parse
> error:  syntax error, unexpected ']'
> inpath\uploads\thumbs\3.jpg on line 52

Source:

```
require_once APPLICATION_PATH . "/../library/ThumbLib.inc.php";
try
{
    $thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../uploads/' . $result . '.jpg', array("correctPermissions"=>true));
    $thumb->resize(240, 200);
    $thumb->save(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../uploads/thumbs/' . $result . '.jpg');
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    var_dump($e);
}
```

I'm really curious. :/

Comment: it refers to the JPG - the line isnt existing code. somehow the library seems to execute the content of the .jpg...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to write a custom function to handle the GD operations... This library (PhpThumbFactory) seems to mess things up badly.

Answer (score 0):

In my application the warning you show above (Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=16) state=0) was caused by creating an empty string with double quotes, so:

```
$var = ""; // Causes the warning
$var = ''; // No warning
```

Hope this helps someone else.